# Deploy Angular To IIS 7.5 Not Working Normal

Tags: angular, iis, build

I', want to deloy My Angular Project But It Lost Component

## My Process

**Step 1:**

I execute cmd:

```
ng-build --prod
```

**Step 2:**

I'm Add Website In IIS With Path Inside **dist**

**Step 3:**

**Index page** working Normal but other component login not found 404

> http://localhost/login HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

In file **App.Module.Ts** I'm Config Routes

```
const routesConfig:Routes=
[
  {path:"kinds",component:KindsComponent},
  {path:"",component:FilmsComponent},
  {path:"films",component:FilmsComponent},
  {path:"login",component:LoginComponent},
  {path:"accounts",component:AccountsComponent},
  {path:"customers",component:CustomersComponent},
  {path:"director",component:DirectorComponent}
];
```

> **Note Again:** http://localhost working normal but other component not found when i build project and deploy in IIS

## Finally:

How to it working? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a redirect to **index.html** in the IIS for any route because in an Angular SPA the app is responsible for the routing not the server See here [Angular routing](https://angular.io/guide/router).

Once e.g. **http://yourdomain/** is requested -> **index.html** gets served and finally the app gets bootstrapped.

But once e.g. **http://yourdomain/login** is requested and there is no server side redirect to `index.html` the server doesn't have any resources mapped to that route and resolves the request with a `404 - Not Found` Error.

Once you serve the **index.html** for any request that would end in a `404 - Not Found` Error (except the assets like css, images fonts) the Angular router takes over and shows the according view once the app is bootstrapped.

**Here an example rewrite rule for the IIS:**

```
<rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```

Comment: best answer! And then install url rewrite for iis. It working!

Comment: Great tip, but it seems to be a copy of this 2017 article (which contains other really useful tips): https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis